# OpenCV inpainting is "blurry" for relatively simple images with mask as bounding boxes of text

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, ocr

Alrogithm:

- Use separate OCR library to identify rectangles around the text
- Use recantagle areas as 1s of the mask
- Run inpaint on image (I've tried different radiuses with similar result)

Result:

- Blurry around rectangles

Example input:

[image]

Example output:

[image]

Questions:

- Is this the best result I can get supposing that I am not able to use the pixels of the characters of the text as the mask?
- Is there an OCR library in existence that would give me the pixels of the characters?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? You mention OCR, so are you trying to read the text in the image, or are you simply trying to remove the text using inpainting? Why would we suppose that you are "not able to use the pixels of the characters of the text as the mask"? Are your actual images more complex than this so that thresholding is not an option? I think we're missing some information here.